# inverted criteria in array autofiltering not working

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question so I am trying my best to follow the rules.

I have tried modifying a piece of autofiltering code that works for a single string variable. The working code is:

```
Dim fruitName As String
fruitName = Range("Fruit[Fruit_Name]")(2)
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("allFruit").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & fruitName
```

Now I want to perform a similar action but having 2 or more chosen fruit. After searching I found I could store the selection of fruit from a named range I created, in a variant array and use this in the criteria.

```
Dim FruitNames() As Variant
FruitNames = Range("ChosenFruitNames")
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("allFruit").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= chosenFruitNames
```

With the above code the criteria in the autofilter works fine. But if I want to filter the table with the fruit that were **NOT** selected it will not work. I have tried doing this with the following `Criteria1:="<>" & chosenFruitNames` but I get a

> Complile error: Type mismatch

I have spent hours searching for a solution but I only find examples for array criteria but not for the specific <> that I need. Below is the code I am using.

```
Dim FruitNames() As Variant
FruitNames = Range("chosenFruitNames")
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("allFruit").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & chosenFruitNames
Rows("3:3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Any help on this will be hugelly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance
Nasos

Answer (score 1):

**Untested**, but give this a try:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim count As Long

count = Range("chosenFruitNames").Count

ReDim arr(1 to count)
For i = 1 to UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = Range("chosenFruitNames")(i).Value
Next i

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("allFruit").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks but unfortunately I get a complile error: Type mismatch and the compiler does not even run it just highlights the "&" in the Criteria1:="<>" & arr

Comment: @Nasos Right! See my update. However, you want what is **not** in the named range to show after filtering, right?

Comment: That is right Brian, as soon as I add the "<>" part it does not work.